# If $f(f(x,a), b) = f(x, p)\; \forall x, a, b$, is it also true that $f(f^{-1}(f(x,a), b), c) = f(x, q) \;\forall x, a, b, c$?

Tags: group-theory, functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $f:\mathcal{F}\times\mathcal{G} \to \mathcal{F}$ be a function of two arguments, defined over finite sets $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$, and bijective with respect to the first argument.  Let $g : \mathcal{F}\times\mathcal{G} \to \mathcal{F}$ be the "inverse bundle," i.e. $g(f(x, a), a) = x$ for all $x \in \mathcal{F}$.

Now suppose that for all $x\in\mathcal{F}$, and $a, b\in\mathcal{G}$, there exists $p\in\mathcal{G}$ such that $f(f(x, a), b) = f(x, p)$; it follows that $f(f(f(x,a),b),c) = f(x,q)$.  Is it then also the case that $f(g(f(x,a),b),c) = f(x,r)$ ?

Comment: $\mathbb Z\bmod\ 2^k$ is a field only when $k=1$; otherwise it is just a commutative ring with unity. Besides, your function $f$ has no properties related to the ring structure of $\mathbb F$ and $\mathbb G$.

Comment: I would call $g$ the "inverse bundle" instead, because for each $a\in\mathbb G$, the function $g(\cdot,a):\mathbb F\to\mathbb F$ is the inverse of the function $f(\cdot,a):\mathbb F\to\mathbb F$...

Comment: I have corrected this as you suggest.  I'm not really conversant with function theory...

Comment: Oops, "inverse bundle" is a term that I coined, it is not a standard term, so I suggest you to put it between quotation marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me at least, it becomes more penetrable if we Schönfinkel it (Curry, if Haskell is more to your taste).

Then you have a map

$$\varphi \colon \mathcal{G} \to S(\mathcal{F}),$$

where $S(\mathcal{F})$ is the group of permutations of $\mathcal{F}$, with the property that

$$\bigl(\forall a, b \in \mathcal{G}\bigr)\bigl(\exists p \in \mathcal{G}\bigr)\bigl(\varphi(b)\circ\varphi(a) = \varphi(p)\bigr).$$

Since $a = b$ is not excluded, that means $\varphi(a)^n \in \varphi(\mathcal{G})$ for all $a \in \mathcal{G}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, hence, since $S(\mathcal{F})$ is a finite group, the identity of $\mathcal{F}$, and the inverses of $\varphi(a),\, a \in \mathcal{G}$ belong to $\varphi(\mathcal{G})$, i.e. $\varphi(\mathcal{G})$ is a subgroup of $S(\mathcal{F})$. In particular, for all $a\in\mathcal{G}$, the map $\varphi(a)^{-1} = \psi(a) \colon x \mapsto g(x,a)$ belongs to $\varphi(\mathcal{G})$, hence is itself of the form $\varphi(b)$ for some $b\in\mathcal{G}$, so indeed

$$ f(g(f(x,a),b),c)=f(x,r)$$

for some $r\in\mathcal{G}$.

Comment: This is helpful, but I don't follow the implication "$\varphi(a)^n \in \varphi(\mathcal{G})$ for all $a \in \mathcal{G}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, [and] $S(\mathcal{F})$ is a finite group, [therefore] the identity of $\mathcal{F}$ and the inverses of $\varphi(a), a \in \mathcal{G}$ belong to $\varphi(\mathcal{G})$".  Specifically, I do not see why $\varphi(a)^n \in \varphi(\mathcal{G})$ entails that $\varphi(a)^n$ *generates* all elements of $\varphi(\mathcal{G})$.  (cont'd...)

Comment: (...) Couldn't $\varphi(\mathcal{G})$ be partitioned into two or more subsets, each generatable by different subsets of $\mathcal{G}$?  Then if $a$, $b$, and $c$ weren't all in the same subset, $r$ wouldn't exist.  Maybe this is ruled out by the earlier assumption, $\bigl(\forall a, b \in \mathcal{G}\bigr)\bigl(\exists p \in \mathcal{G}\bigr)\bigl(\varphi(b)\circ\varphi(a) = \varphi(p)\bigr)$?  It seems plausible but not quite airtight to me.

Comment: The premise that $\bigl(\forall a,b \in \mathcal{G}\bigr)\bigl(\exists p \in \mathcal{G}\bigr)\bigl(\varphi(b)\circ\varphi(a) = \varphi(p)\bigr)$ entails that $\Phi = \varphi(\mathcal{G}) = \{ \varphi(a) : a \in \mathcal{G}\}$ is a subgroup of $S(\mathcal{F})$ [unless $\mathcal{G} = \varnothing$, but then we have a vacuous truth]. It's closed under composition by the premise, so $\varphi(a)\circ\varphi(a) = \varphi(a_2),\, \varphi(a)^{n+1} = \varphi(a)\circ\varphi(a_n) = \varphi(a_{n+1})$. $\varphi(a)$ has finite order, so $\varphi(a)^k = \operatorname{id}_{\mathcal{F}}$ for some $k > 1$ ...

Comment: ... so $\operatorname{id}_\mathcal{F} = \varphi(a_k) \in \Phi$, and $\varphi(a)^{-1} = \varphi(a)^{k-1} = \varphi(a_{k-1}) \in \Phi$. So, $x,y \in \Phi \Rightarrow x\circ y \in \Phi \land x^{-1}\in \Phi$, which, since $\Phi \neq\varnothing$, says $\Phi$is a subgroup of $S(\mathcal{F})$. And thus $\varphi(a)^{-1} = x\mapsto g(x,a)$ is in $\Phi$. In short, yes, the premise rules out a partition of $\varphi(\mathcal{G})$ that would break it.